# I have a discord level stystem and I want to make a leaderboard

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a level discord bot and I want to make a leaderboard of sorting highest level to lowest level. then send a embed on command, here is the code:

```js
const config = require("/Users/kieferlin/Desktop/DiscordBot/config.json");
const fs = require("fs");
const { table } = require('console');

let db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("/users/kieferlin/desktop/discordbot/database.json", "utf8"));

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // ignore bots

  // if the user is not on db add the user and change his values to 0
  if (!db[message.author.id]) db[message.author.id] = {
    xp: 0,
    level: 0
  };
  db[message.author.id].xp++;
  let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
  if (userInfo.xp > 100) {
    userInfo.level++
      userInfo.xp = 0
    message.reply("Congrats, you leveled up")
  }
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (message.content === "!fl level") {
    message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
    message.reply('Here');
    let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0xFFFF0B)
      .addField("Level", userInfo.level)
      .addField("XP", userInfo.xp + "/100");
    if (!member) return message.channel.send(embed)
    let memberInfo = db[member.id]
    let embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0xFFFF0B)
      .addField("Level", memberInfo.level)
      .addField("XP", memberInfo.xp + "/100")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('Level stystem', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gi-nco2WxXdXBNaLRFkH6CMl_2s0MrlsxxnmNYoGQ=s192-c-rg-br100');
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed2)
  };
})
```

Below here is the user that is the code for getting levels. The json file goes like this:

> `{"538797349821087777":{"xp":1,"level":0}}`

Comment: Unable to understand your question? Could you pleaes elaborate as to what challange are you facing?

Comment: hi, the code there is for getting levels, as I want it to sort from highest to lowest, then when a command triggers it it will for an embed of :from highest to lowest level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your members in JSON file is a object `{}`, then convert it into Array and sort it.
Use this part of code

```js
const c = Object.entries(db).sort((a, b)=> b[1].level - a[1].level)
for(const [key, hu] of c) {
  console.log(key, hu)
  // will return like this 
  // "538797349821087777" {"xp":1,"level":0}
}
```

If you want to turn from ID into member, use `await <Client>.users.fetch(key)` inside for() block

Here's the final code with a command called `leaderboard`

```js
                  // don't forget to add async like this
client.on("message", async message => {
    // ...
    if(message.content == "!fl leaderboard") {
        embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        const c = Object.entries(db).sort((a, b)=> b[1].level - a[1].level)
        for(const [key, value] of c) {
            embed.addField(await client.users.fetch(key).tag, `Level: ${value.level} | XP: ${value.xp}`)
        }
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
})
```

By the way, Discord.js v11 will no longer support in the future because v12 has been released in NPM. So please upgrade to v12 in the future :)

Comment: Thanks alot i am testing it rn

Comment: hi, the code does not work since I cant type all of it here can you friend me on discord?
my username is :kief#5555

Comment: Hi how do I turn the userid to a member?